# poweroff nvidia gpu

Tags: arch-linux, nvidia, power-management

lspci result:

```
$ lspci -nn|grep -iP "NVIDIA|Radeon"
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Pitcairn PRO [Radeon HD 7850] [1002:6819]
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cape Verde/Pitcairn HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7700/7800 Series] [1002:aab0]
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation G92 [GeForce 8800 GT] [10de:0611] (rev a2)
```

I currently have 2 gpus in my desktop. My monitors are connected to the AMD one and I only use the NVIDIA one for some cuda programming, so I don't need it otherwise. The reason I don't want the NVIDIA card to keep working is because it's old and very noisy :

```
$ nvidia-smi
Sun Aug 16 23:19:35 2015       
+------------------------------------------------------+                       
| NVIDIA-SMI 340.76     Driver Version: 340.76         |                       
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce 8800 GT     Off  | 0000:05:00.0     N/A |                  N/A |
| 78%   83C    P0    N/A /  N/A |      3MiB /   511MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Compute processes:                                               GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Process name                                     Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0            Not Supported                                               |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I am using the proprietary drivers for both cards: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/catalyst-total/
https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/nvidia-340xx/

Comment: Dupe of http://superuser.com/questions/321657/how-can-i-tell-windows-or-linux-to-put-a-specific-pcie-device-into-sleep-off ? Example answer: echo -n "auto" > /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/power/control' and echo -n "0000:00:02.0" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/i915/unbind

Comment: @AlexStragies followed the commands but the gpu is still powered on. nvidia-smi now outputs: `Unable to determine the device handle for GPU 0000:05:00.0: Unknown Error`